# Como verificar se um nome consta no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, índices, restrição-único

Quero verificar se um nome existe no banco de dados; caso exista não efetuar o cadastro. Usando o código abaixo consigo cadastrar vários usuários com o mesmo nome.

#### cadastro.php

```
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    if(empty($user) or empty($pass)) echo "Preencha todos os campos para continuar!";
    else {
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "user";
    $dbpass = "senha";
    $dbname = "banco";
    $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_users VALUES (NULL,'$user','$pass')");
    if($query) echo "Sua conta foi criada com sucesso!";
    }
```

#### formulario.html

```
    <form name="form3" method="post" action="cadastrar.php">
    <label>USER:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="user"/>
    <label>PASS:</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" />
    <input type="submit" value="CADASTRAR" />
    </form>

    tabela.sql

    CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `username` varchar(250) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(250) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Tentei modificar essas 3 linhas e o cadastro não é feito já pula para mensagem que o usuário existe mesmo sem existir. Como corrigir isso?

```
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_users VALUES ('$user','$pass')");
    if($query) echo "Sua conta foi criada com sucesso!";
    else echo "Usuário já existe, escolha outro nome.";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você colocar uma restrição no banco de dados deve resolver. Isto é feito através da cláusula [`UNIQUE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(250) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
`password` varchar(250) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Index.sql).

Desta forma qualquer `INSERT` que tente usar um valor existente em alguma linha da tabela resultará em erro na *query* e poderá tratar isto.

Quando usa `UNIQUE` pode ser interessante [criar um índice](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) para agilizar a consulta.

```
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username`);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! um pequeno detalhe que faz toda diferença eu tava me matando aqui!!! valeu pelo help.

Comment: Legal. Se resolveu você pode marcar a resposta como "aceita". Eu vi que você não fez isto em nenhuma das perguntas que você fez, provavelmente porque ainda não conhece o recurso. Isto é importante para informar que o problema foi resolvido e dar um reconhecimento a quem respondeu a você. Para entender melhor veja o [tour]. Isto te dá reputação também.

Comment: Também não sabia isso rsrs... agora vou marcar quando útil!

Comment: O voto para coisas úteis você pode dar onde quiser, não só em coisas suas. A aceitação você só pode escolher uma resposta em pergunta que você fez. Aproveite para rever se deve aceitar respostas nas suas outras perguntas passadas.