# Como usar índices além da chave primária?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Tenho uma dúvida sobre esse assunto.

Considere uma tabela com a seguintes colunas:

```
id (chave primaria),
cliente,
cidade,
estado
```

Já entendi que uma consulta com condição `WHERE id = X` ocorreria de forma mais rápida se essa coluna fosse um índice e o motivo disso.

Porém, as consultas nesse cenário hipotético, não seriam baseadas em um filtro de 'id', mas sim em critérios como cidade, estado ou até mesmo o nome do cliente.

Nesse caso, portanto não ficou claro pra mim como o campo 'id' agilizaria a consulta se as buscas não vão utilizá-lo como critério para filtrar/encontrar algo.

Pra melhorar a performance das consultas nessa tabela, teria que transformar

```
cliente,
cidade,
estado
```

em índice?

Comment: Se o campo indexado não está diretamente envolvido na query então o índice não será utilizado. Quanto a criação de novos índices pode ou não ser produtivo, por exemplo o que você colocou: dependendo do volume de dados de sua base um índice sobre o campo estado pode não ser uma boa ideia já que cada entrada do índice poderá apontar para uma lista para uma lista muito grande de registros tornado seu uso ineficaz, lembrando que a existência de um índice onera os processos de inclusão e atualização de seu banco de dados.

Comment: A utilização de ferramentas como o EXPLAIN nas principais consultas podem ajuda-lo a decidir sobre quais índices vale a pena criar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E eu não entendi por que acha que um índice de `id` agilizaria a consulta se as buscas não usam esse campo. A pergunta pressupõe isto e é uma premissa errada.

Índices corretos ajudam seleções com filtros que de alguma forma usam algo contido no índice e mesmo assim não de qualquer forma.

Um índice é como se fosse um dicionário, tem algo classificado e por causa desta classificação é possível fazer uma busca binária, o chamado algoritmo dividir para conquistar, então, grosso modo, o índice olha bem no meio dos itens e verifica se o dado ali é o que você está buscando, se não for ele vê se ele é menor ou maior, se for maior então ele sabe que agora tem que olhar na metade inferior e descartar por completo a metade superior, por isso agora ele olha no 1/4, que é a metade da metade, e ele vai fazendo isso sucessivamente até achar o que deseja. Obviamente que se o dado achado é menor, então ele vai para a metade superior. Claro que o humano não é tão matemático, mas é basicamente assim que ele acha rápido alguma coisa no dicionário. Se as palavras estiverem lá sem ordem alfabética seria bem complicado achar algo, provavelmente só olhando palavra por palavra. O índice é justamente isso.

Outra vantagem é que muitas vezes você quer pegar todos que são iguais ou então pegar na ordem que esse índice oferece, então ele vai andando um por um sem se preocupar com a ordem que foi inserido.

Você só consegue procurar desta forma se o que está procurando está classificado, ou seja, está indexado. Se quer procurar todas as palavras que são adjetivos tem que ir um por um, não dá para usar este índice do dicionário. A não ser que tivesse um outro livro classificado assim que apenas indicaria que página do livro principal está cada palavra. Pode ter vários livros assim, estes são os índices secundários. Em papel isto é quase inviável, digitalmente não.

Uma das vantagens do índice é que você pode ter vários então pode pegar o dado principal e classificá-lo em ordens que atendam diversas demandas diferentes. Um índice pode ser baseado no `id` então achar algo por um determinado `id` é rápido. Toda vez que um `where` ou outra forma que implique um filtro usar o `id` de forma simples assim a busca usará o índice que está classificado por esse `id` e achará o dado no que se chama complexidade logarítmica ou O(log n), por isso se tiver 1 bilhão de itens a pesquisar ele consegue achar em apenas 30 consultas (alguns casos menos por algoritmo melhorado ou porque acha o dado antes de pesquisar tudo, geralmente só gasta 30 se não achar), é absurdamente rápido.

Um índice não precisa ter só um campo, é possível compor vários campos, mas essa composição é como se fosse uma concatenação, então o primeiro campo é o que mais manda, o segundo serve como desempate para o primeiro. E se for buscar algo pelo segundo campo o índice não pode ser usado de forma direta.

Em outras palavras um índice `estado + cidade` é muito diferente de um índice de `cidade + estado`, só para citar um exemplo, não que ele seja o melhor. No primeiro o que manda e pode ser otimizado é o estado, e a cidade serve apenas para desambiguar a busca. No segundo a cidade é que manda, e em alguns raros casos é que poderia usar o segundo campo para desambiguar porque a maioria das cidades já é única. E se o banco de dados estiver normalizado certo o estado nem faz sentido porque a cidade já é única (tem um `id` dela e não o nome).

O índice seria algo assim: `SPSão Paulo`, `SCBlumenau`. Então quando for consultar pelo estado é fácil, se for consultar só pela cidade ele não consegue aproveitar o índice porque a cidade não está no começo, é como no dicionário se você quisesse procurar palavras pela segunda sílaba, não dá, né? Dá olhando uma por uma. O mesmo vale se os campos estiverem invertidos em outro índice: `São PauloSP` ou `BlumenauSC`, agora acha pela cidade, mas não pelo estado. Lembrando que são exemplos em banco de dados não normalizado.

Por experiência eu sei que tem casos que ter um índice com estado e depois cidade faz algum sentido, mas ter cidade e depois estado geralmente não, mas pode ter algum caso. Se você tem um com `estado + cidade` "nunca" precisa ter um só de `estado`, porque nada impede você usar esse índice com dois campos para pesquisar só um deles, desde que ele seja o primeiro.

Então se quer achar rápido e possivelmente em ordem de cidade tem que ter um índice com esse campo. Ele pode estar sozinho ou pode ter outros, mas os secundários só podem ser usados junto com o primário.

Você não tem que transformar nada, tem que criar índice adequado para achar mais rápido o que deseja. Eu sugiro um estudo aprofundado do assunto, caso contrário sempre ficará tentando chutar. Um dos motivos que as pessoas criticam o uso de banco de dados relacional é que elas não sabem usá-lo direito. Aí usam outras coisas e passam ter outros problemas, alguns nem tão aparentes, e acham que estão tendo algum ganho, mas é só ilusão. Quem não sabe usar um RDBMS não conseguirá tomar uma boa decisão do que usar, e aí o melhor é adotar uma solução padrão, que é o RMDBS mesmo :)

Índices são o grande segredo da performance do banco de dados. Existem outros, mas esse é o mais importante. Alguns pontos para ajudar:

- [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101)
- [Como um índice melhora a performance de uma consulta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183305/101)
- [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101)
- [Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101)
- [Quantidade de índices influência no desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361530/101)
- [Índices em consultas no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101)
- [Quais as diferenças entre os algoritmos HASH e BTREE usados em um índice?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258193/101)
- [É necessário criar uma chave primária com auto increment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255270/101)
- [O que são os índices, B-tree, hash, GiST e GIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101)
- [Cardinalidade do índice não atualiza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79889/101)
- [Como criar um índice único baseado em duas colunas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246940/101)
- [Como verificar se um nome consta no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44756/101)

Comment: Obrigado, @Maniero.
Estou iniciando em SQL e, nos materiais que tive acesso, os exemplos sempre transformam a chave primária como um índice. O que pra mim não faz muito sentido já que, se for fazer uma consulta, dificilmente utilizarei esse critério no where.

Daí surge uma outra dúvida: em que cenários seria interessante transformar a chave primário em índice? Pode me dar exemplos?

Comment: Este é disparado o criério mais usado. A chave primária sempre é um índice.